# Trying to sum two columns in SQL Server results in error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm trying to calculate the sum of two separate fields with the query

```
select sum(percent12 + percent21) as total
from finalquery
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 535
>
> Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

However, if I do:

```
select percent12 + percent21 as total
from finalquery
```

I get:

```
(total)
50.0040.00
25.0025.00
100.0 0.00
100.0 0.00
100.0 0.00
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your percentage columns are a `varchar`, the + operator can concatenate strings together, and that is what you're seeing.
I would suggest that you use a `CAST` to a `NUMERIC` data type, especially as it seems that you have a fixed amount of spaces after the decimal.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CAST(percent12 AS NUMERIC(10,2))+ CAST(percent21 AS NUMERIC(10,2))) AS total
FROM finalquery
```

Others have suggested that you `CAST` to a `FLOAT`, though that has known rounding errors (and known workarounds)

> Float rounding error: [SQL Server rounding Error, Giving different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701710/sql-server-rounding-error-giving-different-values)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the values you are trying to sum are varchar/string type and therefore they cannot be summed up.

Try convert them to integer or float (depending of the type) before summing

ie at SQL Server `Select sum(convert(float,x1) + convert(float,x2) )`

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the + operator in your second query, you are actually concatenating two strings. You know they are strings because the error message tells you it's a varchar (i.e. a string).

Instead, you need to convert each field into a number data type and then wrap those in your aggregation. In this case, I chose to cast it as a decimal data type based off of your sample data, but you can cast as integer or other numeric data type as well.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(percent12 AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + CAST(percent21 AS DECIMAL(10, 4))) AS total
FROM finalquery
```

Of course, the obvious answer is to stop storing numbers as strings. If you can modify your database schema, seriously look into changing that.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your schema and you will solve this problem and prevent many others in the future. You should choose the appropriate datatype for each column - don't just blindly select some type of string because it's "easier".