# SQL: Having MAX <> SUM

Tags: sql, sum, max, having, having-clause

It's actually a very simple query, but I don't know why it's showing me values that are actually excluded with the HAVING.

[image: Wrong Entries]

---

Table 1 -> Maintable

- ExpenditureComplete -> Float
- ID

Table 2 -> Subtable (more then 1 Entry for Maintable)

- DurationHour
- MainTable_ID (link to ID of Table1)
- ID

```
SELECT  
            a.ID, 
            b.MainTable_ID,
            MAX(a.ExpenditureComplete) as ExpenditureHours, 
            SUM(b.DurationHour) as DurationHours

    FROM [Table_1] as a
            Inner join
                [Table_2] as b
                    On
                        a.ID = b.MainTable_ID 

    Where a.Inactive = 0 
          and b.Inactive = 0

    Group by
                a.ID, 
                b.MainTable_ID

    Having MAX(a.ExpenditureComplete) <> SUM(b.DurationHour)
```

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: What is your result after running this query? As per your screenshot. It must be 0 rows.

Comment: Please don't post pictures with sample data. Post it as text instead or, even better, a script

Comment: Be careful with FLOAT. Float arithmetic is a dark art and mostly magic, thus it can lead to strange results. Try to convert your data to a fixed point value before you do anything else with it (DECIMAL, NUMERIC, whatever you have in your DBMS).

Comment: Are both columns the same type? If you just need it to work you could throw the whole thing into brackets and select from that with a normal where statement.

Comment: Not able to test this, but can you make a WITH A AS() having the whole query without the HAVING clause, then use Select * FROM A where ExpenditureHours <> DurationHours?

Comment: @Rezu: MSSQL @ Ankit: this from Screenshot

Comment: Try with having round(max(),2)<>round(sum(),2)

Comment: @Rezu ah perfect! It Works! :-) Thank you for the simple and fast response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Having ROUND(MAX(a.ExpenditureComplete),2) <> ROUND(SUM(b.DurationHour),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It tends to become a nuisance with decimals and the use of SUM etc.

This should be possible (although I can't test it at the moment):

```
WITH Aggregated AS (SELECT  
        a.ID, 
        b.MainTable_ID,
        MAX(a.ExpenditureComplete) as ExpenditureHours, 
        SUM(b.DurationHour) as DurationHours

FROM [Table_1] as a
        Inner join
            [Table_2] as b
                On
                    a.ID = b.MainTable_ID 

Where a.Inactive = 0 
      and b.Inactive = 0

Group by
            a.ID, 
            b.MainTable_ID)

SELECT ID, Maintable_ID, ExpenditureHours, DurationHours
FROM Aggregated
WHERE ExpenditureHours <> DurationHours
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the result of at least one FLOAT value to a fixed point value or to another FLOAT.

Floating point arithmetic is dark art and mostly magic, it has it's own limitations and problems, most notably rounding errors.

Depending on the underlaying data, you might see similar values, but in the background they are slightly different.

When you do mission critical comparison on numeric values, do them using a fixed point data type.

As this is described on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187912(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN and in the question [SQL Server rounding Error, Giving different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701710/sql-server-rounding-error-giving-different-values)

> Avoid using float or real columns in WHERE clause search conditions, especially the = and <> operators. It is best to limit float and real columns to > or < comparisons.

Rounding the values may help in some scenarios, but it will give you nasty surprises in the future.